# ajax post big data Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am facing problem for sending big form data using ajax function to server i.e php page. In my page html input fields will add by users for making a quote. And user add many fields then all datas wont posted to server php page. Only some information will save in database and others will lost.

I have used post method in ajax function.

If you have any suggestion for this problem please suggest me.

Comment: There is no limit on a POST request (at least not that you should worry about), but some serverside languages, such as PHP sets a limit, and you can change that limit in php.ini. This value is usually set to 10mb, and that would be a big form if this is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Detect place of the problem

Check POST request. Did you see there your data. In case you see - there is only one reason some where on the server. It couldn't be limit of the post - because in this case you will never get any information on the server and all request would be cancelled.
Another place is in your javascript:
1. you make mistake in name of field
2. bug some where in library
3. bug in your code.

try to debug javascript and understand what happen there.